# How are X.509 certificate revoked?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, x.509

I would like to know how are X.509 certificates revoked.

That is: Say I have an X509 certificate, and I want it to be revoked for whatever reason (e.g., compromise). How do I reach out to the CA? What information do I need to provide? How is that information authenticated?

Is there any standard covering this? Or, instead, each CA follows its own approach? As in, an RFC that specifies the messages that have to be exchanged, their format, how are they authenticated, etc.

All I can find is the RFCs covering CRL and OCSP, but that describes how to check if a credential is revoked, not how to revoke one.

Comment: Did you look this up? I googled your question title and got a lot of material. If you have a CA, have you contacted them?

Comment: Yes, I did Google it. All I found was generic info from some CAs on how to do this in their system (like: "Go here, choose this option, specify the reason, blabla..."), and references to CRL and OCSP specs. But I am not looking for that, I want to know if there is some standard way to do this (like an RFC). Also, it is not that this has happened to me (so I don't have a CA). I am simply analyzing the setting.

Comment: CRL and OSCP is the standard way. They have RFCs. How a CA populates that is up to each org to use whatever forms they prefer (click here, fill in that, etc.)

Comment: I know that. But, as the question says, CRL and OCSP define *how to check if an X509 certificate is revoked*; not how to let the CA know that you want to revoke a certificate, and how does the CA process this request (at least, as far as I know; if I am wrong, please redirect me to the proper CRL/OCSP RFC that defines this.) Yet, doing this securely is crucial, as DoS could occur if this is done wrong.

Comment: "How a CA populates that is up to each org to use whatever forms they prefer (click here, fill in that, etc.)"

Ok, this is kind of an answer. Although, if that is really the case, it is surprising to me. As I say in my previous comment, if this is done wrong, DoS could take place.

Comment: So, do you mean, how does a CA confirm ownership of a cert before adding it to a CRL?

Comment: Yes, I guess (although the cert may not be available to its owner anymore, of course). I mean how does a CA check that I have the right to signal a certificate as "should be revoked"? If this is not done right I could, e.g., have a certificate of yours revoked.

Comment: For instance, in PGP you have "revocation certificates" which, IIRC, is simply a (especially formatted) copy of your public key, signed by its associated private key. You generate it when you create your new public key, and store it securely. Then, if you ever want to revoke that public key, all you have to do is upload the revocation certificate to the key server. It is not a perfect solution, but it is a well defined one, and is secure. But there is no equivalent in X509, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, then if this is what you are getting at, you might reword your question in this light. Because this is far more answerable than your current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a standard protocol to enrol, then that protocol may also have the ability to revoke (e.g. ACME protocol does, and so does CMC).

Otherwise, you should read their CPS (section 4.9) and/or T&C and/or FAQ to figure out their individual process for revocation.

As you say, the protocol should have some form of identity and authorisation otherwise someone could have a field day revoking random users' certificates.

Comment: As exposed in the comments, the question is about the details of identity and authentication

Comment: Thanks, Gareth, this is actually helpful. Is this CPS doc the one you refer to? https://letsencrypt.org/documents/isrg-cp-cps-v5.1/

It kind of confirms what Schroeder mentioned in a previous comment. No standard seems to exist for this, and it is left to the CA's to implement it how they see fit.

Comment: Oh, and the ACME spec precisely contains what I was looking for in Sec 7.6 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-acme-acme#page-56). Thanks!

Comment: The CMC spec too! Leaving the link here in case someone is interested in the future.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5272#section-6.11